# macOS installation couldn't be completed from 10.13.6?

Tags: macos

My MacBook Pro is a year old, and has never had a problem till now.  Just tried to update it, but it wont boot up after. I tried booting in safe mode, but this didn't help. I was able to boot off the main "drive".

The log files have lines like this:

```
Failed to open file <private> [2: No such file or directory]
The main OS Installer distribution (`/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library/Updates/AtomicUpdates/041-53308/041-53308.English.dist`) did not load with error: The file doesn’t exist.
Folder Manager is being asked to create a folder (down) while running as UID 0
```

I've read there are a few options:

1. reinstall OSX. This sounds too drastic.
2. try doing the update again?

Suggestions?

I would add that this laptop has my life and my work on it, I use it 10 hours a day 6 days a week.  If there is risk of losing anything (e.g. having to re install apps or restore from backups) I would rather stick with this version indefinitely if there is no tested fix.

Comment: What exactly did you try to update? If you tried to update macOS, why does a reinstall seems to be too drastic (a major OS update basically is a reinstall)?

Comment: I am seeing the same error.

Comment: @nohillside thanks for the reply.  I don't know exactly what the mac updated, it did it automatically, then after would not boot with an update error.  I am guessing its a minor OS update (i.e. going from 10.13.6 to 10.13.7).  The crux is that I don't what options I now have, and what is the best (safest) solution.  I would not want to reinstall the OS, as this sounds very drastic (coming from windows anyway), and sounds like it could be risky, so am looking for other options to try first.  I assume if its feasibly to try the update again, it will fail with the same error.

Comment: Well, if this laptop is your life I'm sure you have a recent backup so potential data loss shouldn't be an issue. Reinstalling the OS can be done by booting with Cmd-R pressed and choosing the appropriate option, which should leave user-installed application and user data intact (but as usual it's advisable to have backup nevertheless).